# Timing parameters of sequential circuit - digital electronic

Tags: digital-logic, timing, propagation, sequential-logic, constraints

### Problem

> Determine the timing parameters (\$T_\text{cQ,bb}, T_\text{su,bb}, T_\text{h,bb}\$) for the black box logic circuit seen below: -

[image: schematic]

### Attempt

\$T_\text{cQ,bb}\$ is the time it takes for the output \$F\$ to be valid after the clock has ticked, so \$T_\text{cQ,bb} = T_\text{cQ,prop,REG4} + T_\text{prop,AND4}\$.

\$T_\text{su,bb}\$ is the required time the input must remain stable **before** a clock tick, for the output to behave correctly. This must be \$T_\text{su,bb} = T_\text{crit} + T_\text{su,REG4}\$, where \$T_\text{crit} = 3T_\text{prop,AND} + T_\text{prop,INV}\$.

### Question

\$T_\text{h,bb}\$ is the required time the input must remain stable **after** a clock tick, for the output to behave correctly. I am not sure how to determine this for a black box. What is the method for doing this?

Comment: just a comment - it's not a black box if you can see inside :-)

Comment: If TcQ,bb=TcQ,REG4+Tprop,AND4, what about AND3, NOT1, AND2, and AND1?

Comment: @rdtsc Are you implying that I have made mistakes? If so, please feel free to write an answer covering that.

Comment: @danmcb I read the assignment as "Find the timing parameters so this block can be treated as a black box"

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is that hold can be negative, implying that you could change the input just before the clock arrives and it would still latch the old value.

Comment: @W5VO Yes, that is how it should be interpreted. I'm aware of the possibility of negative hold time, but I am unsure of the method to derive the expression for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement on \$T_{cQ,bb}\$ is correct. Take your operating conditions into account for minimum and maximum. You might need them for the next stages.

Operating conditions include commonly load, temperature, and supply voltage.

---

You calculate \$T_{su,bb}\$ correctly as the sum of all gates' propagation delay and the register's setup time, since the input signals are *additionally* delayed by the gates.

Please be aware that you need to use the maximum of the propagation delay \$T_{crit}\$ for \$T_{su,bb}\$, according to your operating conditions.

---

The same thinking model is true for the hold time. The input signals are still delayed by the gates. But because the hold time is a necessary delay at the register's input, the resulting black-box' hold time is shortened by the gates' delays.

You mention the term \$T_{cont,comb}\$ the first time in a comment as the minimum propagation delay:

> [...] are you sure it shouldn't be \$T_{cont,comb}\$ instead of \$T{crit}\$, where \$T_{cont,comb}\$ is the guaranteed time the output of the combinational circuit in front of the DFF will stay unchanged, after a change in the input has happened?

Therefore, the formula is \$T_{h,bb} = T_{h,REG4} - T_{cont,comb}\$. Again, your operating condition apply.

This diagram may help you understand the relations:

[image]

Depending on the specific values, the resulting hold time may become negative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two things: (1) In the formula \$T_\text{h,bb} = T_\text{h,REG4} - T_\text{crit}\$ are you sure it shouldn't be \$T_\text{cont,comb}\$ instead of \$T_\text{crit}\$, where \$T_\text{cont,comb}\$ is the guaranteed time the output of the combinational circuit in front of the DFF will stay unchanged, after a change in the input has happened?
(2) Can you say something about how to calculate \$T_\text{cQ,bb}\$?